# Ceiling of any Real Number Proof

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove or disprove:

For any real number $x$, if $⌈x⌉ − x ≥ 1/2 $ then $ ⌈2x⌉ = 2⌈x⌉ − 1$.

How would one solve this question, because i cant seem to solve it just as is, am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any $x$, we have $\lceil x\rceil$ is the unique integer such that $x+1 > \lceil x \rceil \geq x$.

Note that if $\lceil x \rceil \geq x+\frac 12$ then $2\lceil x \rceil \geq 2x+1$. On the other hand, of course it is true that $2\lceil x \rceil < 2x+2$, so $2x+1 \leq 2\lceil x \rceil \leq 2x+2$, hence it follows that $2\lceil x \rceil = \lceil 2x+1\rceil$.

Now , $2x+1 \leq \lceil 2x+1 \rceil < 2x+2 \implies 2x \leq \lceil 2x+1 \rceil -1 < 2x + 1$, and therefore it follows that $\lceil 2x+1\rceil - 1 = \lceil 2x\rceil$. Therefore, by the equality from the previous paragraph, $2\lceil x \rceil - 1 = \lceil 2x\rceil$.

Comment: I think you mean "$< 2x+2$" in the start of your last paragraph. Otherwise a nice proof.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you , and your proof is also very nice.

Answer (score 1):

$⌈x⌉ − x ≥ 1/2
$

Let
$\lceil x \rceil
= n
$,
so
$n-1 < x \le n$.

We are given $n-x \ge \frac12$,
so that
$n-\frac12 \ge x$.

If
$m = \lceil 2x \rceil$,
then
$m-1 < 2x \le m$.

We want to show that
$m = 2n-1$.

We have
$n-1 < x \le n-\frac12$,
so
$2n-2 < 2x \le 2n-1$.

Since
$m-1 < 2x \le m$,
$m-1 < 2n-1$
and
$2n-2 < m$
so that
$m < 2n$
and
$m > 2n-2$.

Since $m$ and $n$ are integers,
these imply
$m \le 2n-1$
and
$m \ge 2n-1$
so that
$m = 2n-1$
as desired.

Note that the basic inequality
for integers is that
$a > b$
implies
$a-1 \ge b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lceil x\rceil=:n$. Then $\lceil x\rceil-x\geq{1\over2}$ implies $n-1<x\leq n-{1\over2}$, hence $2n-2<2x\leq 2n-1$, as claimed.